# create java hashmap with Unity AndroidJavaObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xamarin.android, mono

I have a method in my java library that gets a Map as an input. 

 
here is my java method

```
public void myMethod(Map<String, String> map){
    //do some thing with this map
}
```

And my C# code in Unity

```
AndroidJavaObject javaMap= new AndroidJavaObject("java.util.HashMap");
javaMap.Call("put", "key1", "value1");
AndroidJavaClass javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.alirezaahmadi.android.sdk.core.BaseAPI");
javaClass.CallStatic("myMethod", javaMap);
```

I can try some code like this but Map is a generic class and this code doesn't work

when i run this i get this error

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='put' signature='(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='put' signature='(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
```

How can i fix this and path a java hashmap to this method. BTW I can not change the java code.

Comment: Don't you think it would be useful to post your Java code as well so that we can see the `myMethod` method? Maybe tell us which line of from the C# is causing the error. With what you have now there is no way one can figure out your problem.

Comment: In addition to the "myMethod" method, AndroidJavaObject.Call() takes a method as its first input, which in your case would be "put". It is not apparent whether or not this method exists from your explanation - which should solve your problem if it does not.

Comment: @ryemoss I'm trying to create a java map. error will be rise in line 2 when I call put method of Java Map class. The problem is Map class is generic and put takes generic arguments not just strings.

Comment: How to write a reverse function? convertMapToDictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of trying I found this code to convert my C# dictainary to AndroidJavaObject HashMap

```
public static AndroidJavaObject CreateJavaMapFromDictainary(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    AndroidJavaObject javaMap = new AndroidJavaObject("java.util.HashMap");
    IntPtr putMethod = AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(
        javaMap.GetRawClass(), "put",
            "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

    object[] args = new object[2];
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in parameters)
    {

        using (AndroidJavaObject k = new AndroidJavaObject(
            "java.lang.String", kvp.Key))
        {
            using (AndroidJavaObject v = new AndroidJavaObject(
                "java.lang.String", kvp.Value))
            {
                args[0] = k;
                args[1] = v;
                AndroidJNI.CallObjectMethod(javaMap.GetRawObject(),
                        putMethod, AndroidJNIHelper.CreateJNIArgArray(args));
            }
        }
    }

    return javaMap;
}
```

Then i simply call my method and path the map like this

```
AndroidJavaObject javaMap = CreateJavaMapFromDictainary(myDictainry);
AndroidJavaClass javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.alirezaahmadi.android.sdk.core.BaseAPI");
javaClass.CallStatic("myMethod", javaMap);
```

Comment: In case anyone wants to use this with a string, object hashmap. They  should be very careful with assuming that the value is always 'compatible' with the new String() java constructor arguments - e.g. Object is not valid, neither is many array types. To make the code handle more types you should use the static String.valueOf - it does handle arrays and objects.   Like this . `var stringClazz = new AndroidJavaClass("java.lang.String"); var value = stringClazz.CallStatic<string>("valueOf", kvp.Value);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of Reza's solution that I use:

```
public AndroidJavaObject ConvertDictionaryToJavaMap(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary) {

    AndroidJavaObject map = new AndroidJavaObject("java.util.HashMap");
    IntPtr putMethod = AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID(map.GetRawClass(), "put", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    foreach (var entry in dictionary) {
        AndroidJNI.CallObjectMethod(
            map.GetRawObject(),
            putMethod,
            AndroidJNIHelper.CreateJNIArgArray(new object[] { entry.Key, entry.Value })
        );
    }
    return map;
}
```